# Gson parsing on android with proguard

Tags: java, android, gson, proguard

I only have a parsing problem with Gson when I use proguard. In debug mode and release mode without proguard, everything work fine.

This is my json string :

> {"tables":[{"name":"Profile","columns":[{"label":"id","type":"text","primary":true},{"label":"name","type":"text"},{"label":"age","type":"integer"},{"label":"human","type":"integer"},{"label":"gear","type":"Gear","custom":true,"list":true}]},{"name":"Gear","columns":[{"label":"id","type":"text","primary":true},{"label":"type","type":"text","enum":true},{"label":"name","type":"text"},{"label":"id_Profile","type":"integer","foreign_key":true}]},{"name":"Animal","columns":[{"label":"id","type":"text","primary":true},{"label":"name","type":"text"},{"label":"magic","type":"integer"},{"label":"id_Profile","type":"integer","foreign_key":true}]}]}

These are my POJOs :

```
public class Database {
    private List<Table> tables;

    public List<Table> getTables() {
        return tables;
    }

    public void setTables(List<Table> tables) {
        this.tables = tables;
    }
}

public class Table {
    private String name;
    private List<Column> columns;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Column> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(List<Column> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
 }
```

I read the file containing the json string and parse it this way :

```
public Database getDatabase(Context context) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open(PATH);
    String schema = getJsonSchema(stream);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(schema, Database.class);
}
```

But when I try to call the method `getTables()` from my `Database` object :

```
for (Table table : database.getTables()) {
    //...
}
```

I receive this error : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference`. I have included those [rules](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) for proguard. Any idea what's the reason ?

Comment: try @Keep annotation on  your class

Comment: Wow it works ! thanks. When one should use the @Keep annotation or set a rule in the proguard file to keep classes ?

Comment: Why does this have the `kotlin` tag?

Comment: My bad, I removed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As darwin commented, adding the `@Keep` annotation to my POJOs classes fixed the issue